# Polymorphic association undefined method `build_product'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am struggling to see what I am doing wrong here..

I have an order model which needs to be able to hold one product, the product needs to be polymorphic.

I have a product/model called orthosis_specification and for some reason I am getting this error when I use it in a fields_for creation.

Migration -

```
class CreateOrders < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :orders do |t|
      t.datetime :order_date
      t.datetime :date_required
      t.boolean :correct
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :practitioner, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :product, polymorphic: true
      t.references :shipping_address, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :invoice_address, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Order Controller -

```
  def new
    @order = Order.new
    @order.build_patient
    @order.build_product #Also tried: @order.build_orthosis_specification
  end
```

Order Model -

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :patient
  belongs_to :product, polymorphic: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :patient,
                                reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['first_name'].blank? },
                                allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product,
                                reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['transfer_name'].blank? },
                                allow_destroy: true

  def to_s
    name
  end
end
```

Orthosis Specification Model -

```
class OrthosisSpecification < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :order, :as => :product, class_name: 'Order'
end
```

Order View -

```
  <%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <% if @order.errors.any? %>
  <% end %>

<%= f.fields_for :orthosis_specification do |fa| %>
```

Actual error message -

```
undefined method `build_orthosis_specification' for #<Order:0x007f8950e29970>
```

Orthosis Specification Migration -

```
class CreateOrthosisSpecifications < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :orthosis_specifications do |t|
      t.string :transfer_name
      t.string :modifications
      t.string :primary_mods
      t.string :top_opening
      t.string :side_opening
      t.string :chape_position
      t.string :scan_file
    end
  end
end
```

Any help would be massively appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What is your error exactly ? can you update your question with the error message please ?

Comment: Can you add the migration for the orthosis_specification table please ? I think I got your problem, but I want to be sure.

Comment: Awesome thanks Caillou, have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polymorphic associations don't generate the build_xxx methods. You can  create a new product only if you know what kind of product you want to create :

```
#Creating a new OrthosisSpecification product associated with @order :
@order.product = OrthosisSpecification.new
```

Documentation : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Right... I need to change my glasses x_x I didn't see the `belongs_to` at first.

Comment: You said that your error was `undefined method 'build_orthosis_specification'`... you got the same thing with `build_product` ?

Comment: Haha. This is why it's driving me crazy, looks like it should work!

Comment: I get this error with `build_product`: `undefined method build_product for #<Order:0x007ff53c64eae0>`

Comment: I got it ! The polymorphic association doesn't create the same methods, you don't have a `build_xxx` with it. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Thanks for your help Caillou! Sorted that error. Got another one now: `unknown attribute 'orthosis_specification' for Order`. I'll open another question though.

Comment: Your polymorphic association only gives you the `product` method for your `Order` model. `@order.product` returns an OrthosisSpecification only if it already has a related OrthosisSpecification.

Comment: Thanks, however it's happening on the create method for Order, not a later showing.

Comment: Create a separate question with all the info needed to answer this second problem, and notice me. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: I meant "notify me", sorry.

Comment: Thanks @Caillou http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33522095/unknown-attribute-on-polymorphic-nested-form-object-creation