# unknown attribute on polymorphic nested form object creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations, fields-for

I am trying to create an associated polymorphic object through fields_for.

I am getting an unknown attribute error though when the parent is created, are the @order params not getting through somehow?

Parent/Order controller -

```
# GET /orders/new
  def new
    @order = Order.new
    @order.build_patient
    @order.product = OrthosisSpecification.new
  end

# GET /hotels/1/edit
  def edit
    @order.build_patient
  end

  # POST /orders
  # POST /orders.json
  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def order_params
        params.require(:order).permit!
    end
```

Form -

```
  <%= form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <% if @order.errors.any? %>
  <% end %>

<%= f.fields_for :orthosis_specification do |fa| %>
```

Order Model -

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :patient
  belongs_to :product, polymorphic: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :patient,
                                reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['first_name'].blank? },
                                allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product


end
```

Full error -

```
unknown attribute 'orthosis_specification' for Order.
```

order_params -

```
>> order_params
=> {"patient_attributes"=>{"first_name"=>"", "last_name"=>"", "dob"=>"", "sex"=>"1", "diagnosis"=>"1", "posterior_flattening"=>"1", "circumference"=>"", "ap"=>"", "ml"=>"", "ci"=>"", "frontal_area"=>"1", "parietal_lateral"=>"1", "ear_position"=>"1"}, "orthosis_specification"=>{"transfer_name"=>"1", "modifications"=>"1", "primary_mods"=>"1", "top_opening"=>"1", "side_opening"=>"1", "chape_position"=>"1"}, "order_date"=>"", "date_required"=>""}
```

params -

```
authenticity_token"=>"v6gVARW+vnApuZpit6IW81ouytlWWQa1Orb4kymseESZmgiFI4KYhOrYyRQuu7yn3mijRp9m7LlFxQlMq7OaAA==", "order"=>{"patient_attributes"=>{"first_name"=>"", "last_name"=>"", "dob"=>"", "sex"=>"1", "diagnosis"=>"1", "posterior_flattening"=>"1", "circumference"=>"", "ap"=>"", "ml"=>"", "ci"=>"", "frontal_area"=>"1", "parietal_lateral"=>"1", "ear_position"=>"1"}, "orthosis_specification"=>{"transfer_name"=>"1", "modifications"=>"1", "primary_mods"=>"1", "top_opening"=>"1", "side_opening"=>"1", "chape_position"=>"1"}, "order_date"=>"", "date_required"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Order", "controller"=>"orders", "action"=>"create"}
```

Orthosis Spec Model -

```
class OrthosisSpecification < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :order, :as => :product, class_name: 'Order'
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :order
end
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Take a look at `params` vs `order_params`. Post the values. Also post your order model.

Comment: Thanks Dickie, do you mean something like this? `@order.product = OrthosisSpecification.new(params[:something])`

Comment: Can you copy/paste the content of the error, please ? Can you also print the content of `order_params` just after `@order = Order.new(order_params)` so we can see what's inside ?

Comment: No, i meant what are the values of them after submitting the form. I assume `OrthosisSpecification` is a `Product`? If so `accepts_nested_attributes_for` only works with the side that has `has_` on in.

Comment: Thanks guys, looks like it is submitting things correctly. Must be an issue with the model associations. More info here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33517572/polymorphic-association-undefined-method-build-product

Comment: Have you tried `f.fields_for :product` instead of `f.fields_for :orthosis_specification` ?

Comment: Yeah, this gives a `Cannot build association "product". Are you trying to build a polymorphic one-to-one association?` error : /

Comment: You pasted your error, but not the full message : which file and which line is it ?

Comment: I'm using better_errors, which separates it out a bit. Both errors occur here -
`createapp/controllers/orders_controller.rb`,
on this line -
    `@order = Order.new(order_params)`. Thanks for looking again Caillou.